# Discrepancy in Primary/Election stage descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, documentation

The sidebar description for the ["Primary" phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary) of The Stack Overflow Moderator Election, [Armadillo Edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111270/should-that-be-2012-moderator-election/111283#comment288496_111283) says that ten candidates will advance to the "Election" phase:

[image: Primary description: "After 4 days, the top 10 candidates..."]

Whereas the sidebar description for the ["Election" phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=election) says that there will be twelve entrants:

[image: Election description: "In the election phase, 12 candidates..."]

Some kind of "phase shift", perhaps?  A statistical exercise involving dummy ballot choices? A duo of <del>planted Manchurian</del> hand-picked extra candidates?

Comment: w00t! Ten thousand unicorn points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch - fixed and deployed.

Comment: Heh Rebecca was faster :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reporting this - we've fixed it up.

Comment: +1 for being 22 seconds faster than Geoff :)

Comment: Thanks -- accepted Geoff's answer to help the poor guy get to 10k! :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - he doesn't need to get to 10K, he's got a diamond after his name ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: All the more reason -- the site he works on, and can't get no respect? :p

Comment: Since Geoff was the one to actually push the change, I'll let it slide. (;

Answer (score 5):

I think the first message is in **decimal** and the second is in **[octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)**.

As the old joke goes:

> Why do programmers get Halloween and Christmas confused?
>
> Because **Oct31 = Dec25**

Dec10=Oct12 also.

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately leads to another question (though not necessarily a bug): why is 150 rep required for the primary, but only DEC 104 (= OCT 150) for the election?

Comment: Reputation is always measured in decimal, obviously.  Moderator counts go from Decimal to Octal because of narwhals.