# Another election description discrepancy -- how many nominees go to Primary?

Tags: support, election, documentation

I'm afraid there's another [mismatch in the phase descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111349/discrepancy-in-primary-election-stage-descriptions) of the [Armadillo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111270/should-that-be-2012-moderator-election/111283#comment288496_111283) Stack Overflow Moderator Election.

The [Nomination phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=nomination) sidebar says only 30 candidates will advance to the primaries:
[image: "After 7 days, the top 30 nominees..."]

<sub>Which was causing [some consternation](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-8046958) w/r/t YOU's rather non-committal nomination.</sub>

Whereas the [Primary phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=primary) sidebar says that *all* candidates will advance:

[image: "In the primary phase, all nominees advance..."]

Presumably the second one is correct. <sub>That should make things a little calmer.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct right now.

A maximum of 30 candidates will be in the primary phase, so if there are more than 30 nominees when the nomination phase ends, the top 30 by rep will be taken.

The latter one says that everyone in the primary phase advances to preliminary community voting ahead of the final election phase.  However, only 30 make it to that point.

Comment: So you're saying that the text on the primary phase is going to (perhaps automatically) change if more than 30 nominations occur?

Comment: Hmm, the latter one could just actually mean "all nominees in the primary phase advance to preliminary community voting", which is also accurate.  Will ponder.

Comment: Okay, I believe I understand what you are saying. I think using the word "advance" to convey movement from one phase to the next _and within_ one phase is confusing. 30 people "advance" to the Primary, then all of those "advance" to a ¿sub-phase? called "preliminary community voting" (which is all there is to the Primary anyways). Thanks for the clarifications, though!

Comment: I agree with Josh: the wording on the primary phase description is confusing. How about “In the primary phase, all retained nominees are subject to preliminary community voting.”?